# How can I scan in Japanese (potentially other multi-byte) text from a UTF-8 encoded file in Python?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to read and interpret Japanese text from a UTF-8 encoded file using Python, and I'm having a strange issue; the returned string is always completely empty. I'm not doing anything unorthodox (I think?):

```
with open(inputFile, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as word_list:
    text = word_list.read()
```

If the file is English characters only, `print(text)` returns the expected string of input characters, but when I have Japanese characters only in the file, `print(text)` returns `''`.

Can anyone provide pointers here?

Comment: Is your terminal set up to use UTF-8 encoding?  What happens if you try to simply `cat` your file to the terminal? Once you have that fixed I suspect your program will work.

Comment: Is `len(text)` zero or something else?

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Let me double-check terminal settings when I get home; I can definitely confirm that len(text) is zero, however